# springboot mongodb framework find by binary data type

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, binary

It is possible to find by binary field with springboot mongodb framework?

I have a binary field ("customer.telephone"), and I need to search with:

```
Criteria.where("customer.telephone").in("gKxwfyWwD2pOSnLlBMaQhnW6UwbDY0I6X1jVvWBIBmFwoaNdDooA02iTbjreUMOzeQ=="))

"customer" : {
        "id" : 25203836,
        "code" : "PEPODENL0000000001901",
        "identification" : BinData(0,"gOjp6Tnq4rA3G4YjIADecwjGWlbm7Nv8...   (49 bytes)"),
        "name" : BinData(0,"gOADFJ0d9/MeFz6KfpoJ/8pDpN8k9L3k...   (65 bytes)"),
        **"telephone" : BinData(0,"gKxwfyWwD2pOSnLlBMaQhnW6UwbDY0I6...   (49 bytes)"),**
```

Thanks in advance,